# Event Handler when a Row is deleted from Table View

Tags: java, javafx-8

i need to know how to catch the event that happens when a row is deleted from the TableView and the index of the row. At this moment when a row is deleted from the Table View the TableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection() method is called. But i want is to select the last index available in the Table View.

Tableview.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect() is not an option, because sometimes a row is deleted automatically.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a table with type, for example, `Person`:

```
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change ;

// ....

TableView<Person> table = ... ;

table.getItems().addListener((Change<? extends Person> c) -> {
    while(c.next()) {
        if (c.wasRemoved()) {
            int numRemoved = c.getRemoved().size();
            int index = c.getFrom();
            System.out.println(numRemoved + " items removed from table at index "+index);
        }
    }
});
```

The [`ListChangeListener.Change` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) describes the values returned by `c.getFrom()`, `c.getTo()`, `c.wasRemoved()`, `c.getAdded()`, etc. under various scenarios.

Comment: It works but the correct expression was  table.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person> c) -> {}); please edit. Regards.

Comment: Ok i got this. Thanks !!